# Insert values with if condition with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make register member page. If a new member insert an email which has been already exist, then there will be a notification saying that the email is exist. But if the email has not been exist, the values they insert in the form will be send to database.

I don't know what is wrong with my code bellow. It just blank and doesn't send anything to databse. I need a help.

```
<?php
//conection:
 $link = mysqli_connect(".com","klaudia","intheclaud","elektro") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//consultation:

 $member_id=$_GET['member_id'];
 $member_name=ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['member_name']));
 $member_email=$_POST['member_email'];
 $member_password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['member_password']);
 $member_phone=$_POST['member_phone'];
 $member_address_satu=ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['member_address_satu']));
 $member_address_dua=ucwords(htmlspecialchars($_POST['member_address_dua']));
 $member_reference=$_POST['member_reference'];



  $query = "SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_email='$member_email '" or die("Error in  the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

 //execute the query.

 $result = $link->query($query);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "This email you are using has been registered before";
  }
 else {

 mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO member_registry (
                                                  'member_id', 
                                                  'member_name', 
                                                  'member_email', 
                                                  'member_password', 
                                                  'member_phone', 
                                                  'member_address_satu', 
                                                  'member_address_dua', 
                                                  'member_reference') 
                                    VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)";
```

?>

I have tried to check the connection and the database. Everything works fine here. When I insert someone name which has been in the table of the database, it will echo that the email already exist. and vice versa.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name='Klaudia '" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

    //execute the query.

    $result = $link->query($query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "This email you are using has been registered before";
    }
    else {
    echo "This email you are using has NOT been registered before";   
     }
```

**[UPDATE]**

```
      mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO member_registry (
                                                  'member_id', 
                                                  'member_name', 
                                                  'member_email', 
                                                  'member_password', 
                                                  'member_phone', 
                                                  'member_address_satu', 
                                                  'member_address_dua', 
                                                  'member_reference') 
                                    VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)");
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: It just blank and doesn't send anything to databse

Comment: Add error checking to the query like you do with the connection.

Comment: In your INSERT statement, either remove the single quotes around your column names or change them to backticks.

Comment: close the mysqli_query function

Comment: You are also missing a `}` but I dont know if that is an error when copied over

Comment: @chriz, I am not missing that. #suby, #Sean, & #Jay it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @klaudia the code you have provided says otherwise. You are also missing a `}` before the `?>` and a `)` at the end of `mysqli_query` before the `;`

Comment: @chriz I have added this but it doesn't change the situation. Is there a way to check the problem?

Comment: @klaudia could you update your question with the most recent code so I can take a look please?

Comment: @chriz I just updated it, not much change.

Comment: Have you tried running it similar to how you are running the first one? using `$link->query($query);` ?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT ..." or die(...)` is UTTERLY pointless. You're not running a query. You're just defining a string in PHP.

Comment: @Marc B, actually I am still learning how to works with mysqli. And  I just follow the instruction in php.org if you don't mind, please tell me which what I need to change that. thanks

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error(...)` is for when you're actually doing mysql operations. defining a string (that happens to contain sql) is NOT a mysql operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't handle this by two separate queries (at least without a transaction).
Instead [create a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) that doesn't allow the same email address twice in the table and check for the specific [ER_DUP_ENTRY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) error code to detect doublets.

[sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
define('MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY', 1062);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error('connection failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}


$result = $mysqli->query('
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
        id int auto_increment,
        email varchar(128),
        primary key(id),
        unique key(email)
    )'
);
if ( !$result) {
    trigger_error('create table failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (email) VALUES (?)');
if (!$stmt) {
    trigger_error('prepare failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$result = $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
if ( !$result) {
    trigger_error('bind_param failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}

foreach( array('email1', 'email2', 'email1') as $n=>$email ) {
    echo $n, ' ', $email;
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if ( $result ) {
        echo " ok\r\n";
    }
    else {
        if ( MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY==$stmt->errno ) { // <-- here's the test for the duplicate entry
            echo " duplicate\r\n";
        }
        else {
            var_dump($stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
0 email1 ok
1 email2 ok
2 email1 duplicate
```

Comment: Does it mean that I just need to make the column of email adress as unique key? Then what I have to do in the config to say that the email is already exist. Can you give me more explanation with an example,please?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax. You don't close your function.
Also you shouldn't use single quotes around your coumn names.

> ```
> mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO member_registry (
>                                                   `member_id`, 
>                                                   `member_name`, 
>                                                   `member_email`, 
>                                                   `member_password`, 
>                                                   `member_phone`, 
>                                                   `member_address_satu`, 
>                                                   `member_address_dua`, 
>                                                   `member_reference`) 
>                                     VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)");
> ```